# The method fromQuery(String) gives an error in an eclipse dataflow project. How should I solve it?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

The error below is generated:

> The method fromQuery(String) is undefined for the type
>   BigQueryIO.Read.

And, it occurs in the following line :

```
PCollection<TableRow> somename = p.apply(BigQueryIO.Read.fromQuery("Select * from abc:def.ghi"));
```

Comment: Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question.

Comment: What version of the Java SDK are you using? Please add that to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like `fromQuery(String)` belongs to `BigQuery.Read.Bound`. You're missing the `.Bound`.

Try:

```
PCollection<TableRow> somename = p.apply(BigQueryIO.Read.Bound.fromQuery("Select * from abc:def.ghi"));
```

Check out the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/BigQueryIO.Read.Bound).

Comment: Well, it didn't work. Read the documentation already. The error is on the line **.fromQuery**